# Pop-Up Message With out opening a page

Tags: web, popup

Well, This is the thing, I was navigating the internet any page, and suddenly, A Pop Up windows appeared on screen from my ISP (To remind me I didn't pay today) ... so Do you know how to send that kind of messages without opening the webpage or installing anything on a pc?

Comment: You'd need a plugin of some kind. You can't just tell the browser remotely to pop up over someone else's site. The whole internet would explode if that were possible

Comment: So tell me then how my ISP did that on my new laptop.

Comment: I guess you're using some desktop client app provided by isp that was running in background.

Comment: And Tim pretty much nailed it on his answer. I guess what I'm saying is YOU can't do this unless you provide a browser app that the client installs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was navigating the internet any page...

Since your internet access is through the ISP, they have the ability to manipulate the traffic coming through their hardware. This includes replacing the content of a site, appending content, or inserting content.

Obviously they can't alter the actual site, but if you request "foo.com" and you haven't paid your bill, they can return whatever they want in response to your request.

They could return `<script>window.open()</script>` + the HTML content of "foo.com". Invalid, but browsers will render it. They could return a warning page. They could return an HTTP status code. You get the idea.

If you didn't have your web browser open, then something is installed in the background (whether or not you know it). Most hardware comes with dozens of background services which try to be "helpful".

Comment: You may be right, at least now I have an idea on how to do this if I want to. Thank you